# How to access js file function from dart file for the mobile application flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-method-channel

I want to access the function which I have defined in js file and I need to access that function from my dart file,

I have followed the following way for the access, but when I am trying to access that function from dart file for the web, it's working fine,
But when I am going to access that for mobile app (Android and iOS), then getting an error,

Error:

```
Error: Not found: 'dart:js' import 'dart:js'
```

Ref: https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/

If anyone help for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

Inset `import 'dart:js'` on the very top of your code